# Access UI Widgets from Handler

Tags: android, android-widget, handler

Quick question, can you not access a UI widget from within a Handler? In the following example, the text comes through the message handler and I update the TextView widget but the text is not displayed within the widget.

Example:

```
public class FooActivity extends Activity {

    @InjectView(r.id.show_something) TextView showSomethingText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        someService = new SomeService(this, fooHandler);
    }

    private final Handler fooHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            showSomethingText.setText((String)msg.obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do it from any part of your code provided you are in a main UI thread

Comment: This can cause memory leaks btw.

Comment: In regards to pskink's response, I realize that I can do it from any part of the code, that is why I am mystified why the TextView is not updated.

Comment: In regards to Pedro Oliveira's comment, you mean the way I define the Handler or accessing a TextView from a Handler?  If it is the second, what would be a better approach to update the UI based on a message coming back from the handler?

Comment: are you sure your handleMessage is being called? did you try to add some Log.d calls inside?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the handleMessage is being called, both through Log statements and walking it through the debugger.  It is almost like you update the widget but you need to tell the UI thread to refresh itself.

Comment: setText sets the text, no need for any kind of refresh, maybe msg.obj is empty or something?

Comment: No, there is data, I can see it both stepping through the code using a debugger and through Log.d statements.  No UI widgets (TextView, ListView) seems to be able to be updated from a Handler.

Comment: post your complete code then, i did used Handler to update the UI billion times and it worked